# Identify square icon with filled triangle up icon in iOS status bar

Tags: icon, ios

There's an icon just to the left of the battery percentage icon in the Status bar of my iPhone, which I am unable to identify.

I have tried looking for it in the Apple Support document, but was unable to find it:

- [Status icons and symbols on your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207354)

Does anyone know what does it represent? How can I remove it?

[image]

Comment: It is the Airplay.

Comment: How can I disable it ?  Why is it appearing now?

Comment: You can turn it off - http://resources.parsons.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/AppleTV_Airplay_Mirroring.pdf.

Comment: swipe up to get control panel. Maybe an option appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon represents AirPlay, Apple's technology that lets you mirror screen content from one device to another.

The icon indicates an active AirPlay session where your iPhone screen is mirrored on an AirPlay compatible device (Apple TV for e.g.).

You can learn more about AirPlay in the Apple Support article:

- [How to AirPlay video and mirror your device's screen to Apple TV](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204289)

Turning off the AirPlay session will remove the icon from the Status bar.

Comment: Ok I see.. Never saw it while I'm using iOS and macOS... Is there a way to disable it?\

Comment: You can also turn Airplay on in System Preferences > Displays.

Comment: AirPlay on my mac is already disabled

Comment: Hmmm restarting my iPhone made the icon disappear ! Strange ! Anyway, thanks for having explained my what was this icon :D